# Dynamic updates through events rest api c#

Tags: c#, rest, events, dynamic, server-sent-events

I want to implement a feature like, if anything has been updated on Server-side like in database(the change can be from a client or another resource), then an event should be triggered and i come to know what change has been made. Then, through a rest api, i will send the response to UI with an event code, message and the new data from database.
And on UI, i have the approach to handle the events.
Please, tell me the approach or study material to implement this feature.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are looking for something like broadcasting?

Comment: You want to look at web sockets or signlarR. Establish connection between client and server, when something is updated on server - send message through that connection back to client as you described.

Comment: @A3006 yeah, a type of broadcasting you can say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use bi-directional communication between the clients and server you can use one of the following frameworks depending on your requirments:

- [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)
- [WebAPI and WebSockets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2012/07/17/building-real-time-web-apps-with-asp-net-webapi-and-websockets/)
- [Socket IO](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) (framework for Node.js)
- [Alchemy-Websockets](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/Alchemy-Websockets)
- [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck)
- [SocketCluster](https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster) (framework for Node.js)

Comment: Can we implement SignalR with a Rest Api ? How are we going to know that whether something has changed in database or no, Only then i will send a response?

Comment: Yes, you can develop Web API and use SignalR to update the clients. Have look at the following nuget package : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SignalR/

Comment: You can use the `SqlDependency`class to notify your application on changes in the database: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx

Comment: Thanksalot buddy. Atleast, now i have some idea on how to do it :)